# Need help testing my smart contract. Error cannot read undefined

Tags: error, unittesting

I am testing my smart contract and I am getting this Assertion Error. I do not know or understand what it means and after searching how to fix it online and making some adjustments to my code, I am still getting this error. What could this possibly be? I posted the first part of my test below. Thank you in advance.

```
    import { loadFixture } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";
    import { expect } from "chai";
    import { ethers } from "hardhat";
    import hre from "hardhat";

    let tokenId;
    let listingPrice;
    let owner;
    let horizonsMarketplace;
    let tokenIdSupply;
    let listToken;
    let token;
    let minter;

    describe("HorizonsMarketplace Initiation", function () {
    // We define a fixture to reuse the same setup in every test.
    // We use loadFixture to run this setup once, snapshot that state,
    // and reset Hardhat Network to that snapshot in every test.
    async function deployContractAndSetVariables() {
    const HorizonsMarketplace = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    "HorizonsMarketplace"
    );
    const horizonsMarketplace = await HorizonsMarketplace.deploy();

    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    return { horizonsMarketplace, owner };
    }

    it("should deploy and set the owner correctly", async function () {
    const { horizonsMarketplace, owner } = await loadFixture(
    deployContractAndSetVariables
    );

   it("Check Owner", async function () {
    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const HorizonsMarketplace = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    "HorizonsMarketplace"
    );
   const deploy = await HorizonsMarketplace.deploy();
   expect(await deploy.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
   });

   expect(await horizonsMarketplace.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
   });

   describe("HorizonsMarketplace listing functionality", function () {
    it("Should create a new listing", async function () {
    await token.approve(horizonsMarketplace.address, listingPrice, owner);

   const tx = await horizonsMarketplace.listToken(
    token.address,
    tokenId,
    listingPrice,
    { from: minter }
    );
    expect(token).to.equal(owner);
    expect(listingPrice).to.equal(1);
    expect(tokenIdSupply).to.increase(1);
    });
    });
```